# How to change value kendo grid row items using some data from external combobox?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo grid in which I am using the roweditor function to allow user to change values of networks listed as network1, network2, network3 lets call it as gridNetwork.

I have a combobox on the same page having networks listed same as network1, network2, network3 what was there in grid. The user can select values from this combobox let us call it as comboNetwork.

Based on the selection made in the comboNetwork, the value of the selected row(s) network should also change in gridNetwork.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your code, for example in plunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a jsfiddle,give a try:

[http://jsfiddle.net/Sowjanya51/a2agwrf5/2/](http://Jsfiddle)

Comment: Thanks! this is very useful when we have the static content in the grid. But what if I am using an editor to change the network using the `$scope.netwokDropDownEditor = function (container, options) {
          $('<input required data-text-field="networkName" data-value-field="networkId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoComboBox({
              autoBind: false,
              dataSource: $scope.nwType,
              template: "#=data.networkName#"
            });
        };`

Comment: `dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
          data: sampleData,
          pageSize: 10,
          schema: {
            model: {
              fields: {
                vmName: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                keepTemplate: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                deploy: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                network: { nullable: false, defaultValue: { networkId: "network1", networkName: "Network 1" } },
                powerState: { defaultValue: { state: "false", stateName: "Power Off" } },
              }
           }
         }
   }),`

Comment: I have shared the editor function and the datasource of grid.

Comment: edited the fiddle  :    [link] http://jsfiddle.net/Sowjanya51/a2agwrf5/4/               You can change the observable array or you can change the grid model directly too...

Comment: Thanks @Andrea you really got me out of the problem, I really appreciate.

Comment: @Surendra can you mark it as answer if it helped you so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is on-change function bound to your comboBox that will update your underlying data model that you have bound to your grid.

In that function, update the model, the refresh the grid's datasource that the model is populating.